# waiting on a task in iOS

Tags: ios, background, wait

I have what sounded like a really simple issue at first, and I think still is, but I'm missing the answer.

When my app logs in, I start a background task to download some data from the server.  If that data isn't downloaded by the time the user taps one of two buttons, I want to put up a spinner view and wait until that task is finished.  Once finished, remove the spinner view and then continue to push the view controller.

What I seem to be missing is how to do this and wait so that the main thread isn't blocked.

Once the data is downloaded, I can set a global flag, or send out a notification, but the view controller has to have a way to wait on that condition to either be set, or to know that there was a download error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can do this by 1)your VC is delegate for the service class(which downloads) 2) fire notification once the download is complete, VC will listen to this notification and update UI. **Any UI updating should be done on main thread **

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow is not meant to be used in the way you're using it, so you're going to get downvoted.

But, what you are looking for is [dispatch_async](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). You use it to create queues.

If you need more information, [this page](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) has a good explanation, as well as [this page](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/).